# using wp_editor to edit post title on the front end

Tags: php, wordpress, post, frontend

i'm trying to add the ability for a user to edit the post content on the front end.

i'm adding the following code inside the loop after each post:

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$post = get_post( $post_id, OBJECT, 'edit' );

$content = $post->post_content;
$editor_id = 'editpost';

$editor_args = array(
'media_buttons' => false,
'editor_class' => my_editor,
'textarea_rows' => 10,
'wpautop' => false,
'tinymce' => array( 
'content_css' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/editor-style_single.css' 
    ) 
);

?>
<div id="inline_editor">
<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $editor_args ); ?>
</div>
```

it seems like i can edit the post content itself but i cant manage the editor to show the post title / post name.

how can i edit the post title from the frontend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For editing the title you should use $post->post_title instead of post_content since post_content is the body of your page